# PJSIP Android TLS --Unable to generate suitable Contact header for registration: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)

Tags: android, pjsip

I am trying to make call using pjsip TLS in android.As per pjsip guidelines i built the pjsip library with openssl commands.

I have included following in my config_site.h

> ## define PJSIP_HAS_TLS_TRANSPORT 1
>
> ## define PJ_HAS_SSL_SOCK 1

I can see while building the library OpenSSL included.

> OpenSSL library found, SSL support enabled

I sucessfully  created TLS transportusing below command

```
ep.transportCreate(pjsip_transport_type_e.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_TLS,
                    sipTpTLSConfig);
```

I can see TLS Listener started on my local ip address.
But when i try to register it gives me error

> Unable to generate suitable Contact header for registration:
>   Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)

**Java Code**

```
String sipid = sipURI + username + "@" + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port;
String registrar = sipURI + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port+addTransportTLS;
String proxy = sipURI + switch_ip + ":" + switch_port;
AccountConfig accCfg = new AccountConfig();
accCfg.setIdUri(sipid);
accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri(registrar);
accCfg.getRegConfig().setRetryIntervalSec(60);
accCfg.getNatConfig().setIceEnabled(false);
app.addAcc(accCfg);
```

I did the following as per pjsip docs and added **;transport=tls** to my registrar address. But I still get this error.

Comment: Could you please post your code for registration configuration of your account?

Comment: @McLaLa added code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registration of sip account should be done as code below shows. Also, you have to set port in `TransportConfig` by setting `sipTpTLSConfig.setPort(your_sip_port);`

```
AccountConfig accCfg = new AccountConfig();
accCfg.getSipConfig().getProxies().add("sip:" + your_sip_server_host + ";hide;transport=tls");
accCfg.setIdUri("sip:" + your_sip_username + "@" + your_sip_domain);
accCfg.getRegConfig().setRegistrarUri("sip:" + your_sip_domain);

AuthCredInfoVector creds = accCfg.getSipConfig().getAuthCreds();
creds.add(new AuthCredInfo("Digest", "*", your_sip_username, 0, your_sip_password));

app.addAcc(accCfg);
```

You can keep your code for setting registration interval and disable ice.

Comment: Hi I do have the above lines also.But stil it gives me the same error.

Comment: And you set the port for your transport configuration before you create transport from the endpoint, right?

Comment: yes i did that i do understand that we need to create transport before adding account.If we didnt create transport i would be getting different exception.

Comment: but if i add sips to the uri im able to generate register request.

Comment: ;transport=tls in proxy i didnt do that .that was the reason bro.Thanks for your help.

Comment: you save my life!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in a iOS app we are developing today. I found that I was 'cause we were using TCP as transport, but UDP was the right network transport to use with my Asterisk.

So, I just used UDP instead of TCP and everything worked fine.

Good luck!